# ko.js: Remove entry from observableArray from within

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, observable

Let's assume an observableArray with some entries. I wan't to have a complex html element for each of them. I used components to reuse templates:

```
<!-- ko foreach: searchResults -->
    <entry class="..." params="entry: $data"></entry>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Rendering these items works perfectly. The problem: There's a "x"-button in each of these items which should allow the user to delete the items. Is there a way to manipulate the array from withing the array? Like accessing the parent?

Comment: call a class function with the index of the a"x" button and then cut it out?

Comment: There is a `$parent` scope in ko, but ideal way is to access a unique id from  scope and remove necessary value from array

Comment: Use the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). Note that when using a [`click`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/knockout.js/7101/bindings-form-fields/7835/click#t=201705221437399261205) or other `event` binding to call a method, the `this` context will be set to the child, not the parent. I.e.: you might have to write `$parent.removeEntry.bind($parent)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it with proper ko-scoping:

```
<entry class="..." params="entry: $data, removeItem: $parent.removeItem"></entry>
```